# Search Bar on TableView Does not Work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, uisearchbar

I'm trying to add a search bar to a simple table view consisting of 7 cells of names and small description for each name.

As in the image here:

[image]

I made a class in swift file called Business, that has two attributes: Name and Des.

Here's the code in the view controller:

```
  class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!
var B = [Business]() //candies
var filteredNames = [Business]()

 let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredNames = B.filter { Bu in
        return Bu.Name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
    }

    TableView.reloadData()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    B = [
        Business(Name:"Mariah", Des:"I'm Here to help"),
        Business(Name:"Nada", Des:"Hi"),
        Business(Name:"Atheer", Des:"Hello"),
        Business(Name:"Lojian", Des:"I can Help you"),
        Business(Name:"Nadya", Des:"Hayat"),
        Business(Name:"Omnia", Des:"Yahoo"),
        Business(Name:"Eman", Des:"I have amazing stuff"),
        Business(Name:"Amani", Des:"Yess")
    ]

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    TableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return filteredNames.count
    }
    return B.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.TableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell

    cell.NameLabel.text = B[indexPath.row].Name
    cell.DescriptionLabel.text = B[indexPath.row].Des

    let Bu: Business

    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        Bu = filteredNames[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        Bu = B[indexPath.row]
    }
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
     return cell
}


  }

 extension FirstViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:   
(UISearchController)   {
filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
}
 }
```

I followed this tutorial to do that: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

I don't know whay when I tried to search in simulator the result is always the first cell: Mariah

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: in your code you have set the both the label from the B before you check the condition if it's from filter result or normal, dasdom answer should mostly work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the search result to populate the cells. Replace you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.TableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell

    let Bu: Business

    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        Bu = filteredNames[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        Bu = B[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.NameLabel.text = Bu.Name
    cell.DescriptionLabel.text = Bu.Des

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    return cell
}
```

And, don't use capital first letters for properties.

Comment: How can I not to use the capital letters? In which line of code?

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` and `var b = [Business]()`.

Comment: But why should I not use capital letters for properties?

Comment: Because it is said so in the guide lines.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: @Mariah To clarify, it is standard practice when coding in many languages, including Swift, that method names, property names, and variable names should start with lowercase letters. Class names should begin with uppercase letters.